# Search for a value in multiple nodes in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the structure of my firebase

[image]

I want the user to write a name of the monument and check if the name exists, in the child "France" and "English", can you help?

Example:
I write "tower" and the result is "tower bridge" and "tower eiffel"

```
locaisRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase().child("English language");

      searchViewPesquisaInicial.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            

        return false;

        }

    });
    return view;
```

> method

```
    Query query = locaisRef.orderByChild("name")
                .startAt(text)
                .endAt(text + "\uf8ff");

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                list.clear()

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    list.add(ds.getValue(Locais.class));
                 
                }
               
                seachAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: The way your data is structured now, you will need at least two queries, one for English/bridge and a second for Frace/tower.  Consider changing your structure to support a single query by structuring the child nodes similarly.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of operations cloud firestore allows simpler queries than realtime database, since it allows collection groups:

Query query = db.collectionGroup("landmarks").orderBy("name").startAt(text).endAt(text + "~");

**ATTENTION:** Each collection group requires an index. If you haven't created one manually, the first time you run the query it will throw an exception containing a link. The link can be used to create an index. When the index is created the query will work properly